# Tidy R Data: Searching through factors for specific strings and numbers to duplicate row based on that value

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse

I having trouble tidying up this data.  The pastried.Baked columns are factors and I want to be able to search through the pastries.Baked column for all iterations that are `\\S+[X]\\S+` (value >1), change value to 1, and duplicate the row by that value.

`df <- data.frame(bakery.ID = 1:4, pastries.Baked = c('Large Cake x 3', 'Large Cake x 1', 'Large Cake x 2', 'Medium Cake x 1'))`

Desired Output

| bakery.ID | pastries.Baked |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Large Cake x 1 |
| 1 | Large Cake x 1 |
| 1 | Large Cake x 1 |
| 2 | Large Cake x 1 |
| 3 | Large Cake x 1 |
| 3 | Large Cake x 1 |
| 4 | Medium Cake x 1 |

Answer (score 2):

Using `separate` you may split the text and number in two different columns and use `uncount` to repeat the rows based on number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(pastries.Baked, c('pastries.Baked', 'count'), sep = '\\s*x\\s*', convert = TRUE) %>%
  uncount(count) %>%
  mutate(pastries.Baked = paste(pastries.Baked, 'x 1'))

#  bakery.ID  pastries.Baked
#1         1  Large Cake x 1
#2         1  Large Cake x 1
#3         1  Large Cake x 1
#4         2  Large Cake x 1
#5         3  Large Cake x 1
#6         3  Large Cake x 1
#7         4 Medium Cake x 1
```